# How to catch navigation event in SPFx webpart?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, react, reactjs

Is it possible to catch navigation event inside Sharepoint Framework web part?

I know this is possible in application customizer using `context.placeholderProvider.changedEvent`, but I cannot find anything similar for web parts.

I use ReactJS and I tried `componentWillUnmount`, but it's not invoked.

`window.onbeforeunload`, `window.onhashchange` - don't work either, probably because modern SharePoint pages are not reloaded entirely when navigating through pages.

Answer (score 2):

Try using **context.placeholderProvider.navigatedEvent** instead

This has been suggested as the way going forward. Unfortunately the documentation hasn't been updated to reflect this.

Comment: I assume placeholderProvider exists in extensions context only, not in webparts

Answer (score 1):

I put this in my webpart render method:

```
 this.reactElement = React.createElement(TrForm, formProps);
      var formComponent: TrForm = ReactDom.render(this.reactElement, this.domElement) as TrForm;//render the component
      window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        debugger;

        if (formComponent.state.isDirty) {
          var dialogText = "You have unsaved changes, are you sure you want to leave?"
          e.returnValue = dialogText;
          return dialogText;

        }
      }
```

Comment: I guess this is being triggered before navigation occured?

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like:

In myWebpart constructor:

localStorage.getItem('location') === window.location.href ? "do nothing" : "aha, navigation occurred !"
save window.location.href in localStorage as 'location' // every time

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best option that I can think of now is to use react-router's history.listen(location => () => locationChangeHandler(location)),
works perfectly in React app, although haven't tried with SPFx yet